# passing ng-model variable through an ng-click to a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use a select and options tag with HTML. The data is being brought through using `ng-repeat`, when the user chooses an item from the list and presses the get button, I want to pass what the user has chosen from the options list into a function using `ng-click`

HTML

```
<ul>
 <li class="col-xs-4"><a href="#favourites">Favourites</a></li>
</ul>
<div ng-controller="favouritesController">
 <select class="col-xs-12" name="weather">
  <option ng-repeat="weatherList in weatherLists" ng-model="city">{{weatherList.place}}</option>
 </select>
 <div class="col-xs-12">
  <button type="button" name="button" class="deleFav" ng-click="getFavWeather(city)">Get</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

 myApp.controller('favouritesController', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $route, $location) {
  $scope.getFavWeather = function(weatherList){
   console.log("yes yes yes")
   console.log($scope.city)
  }
 })
```

Comment: `ng-model="city"` has to be an attribute of the `select` tag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add ng-model on select and use it in your ng-click :

```
<div ng-controller="favouritesController">
 <select class="col-xs-12" name="weather" ng-model="citySelected">
  <option ng-repeat="weatherList in weatherLists" ng-model="city">{{weatherList.place}}</option>
 </select>
 <div class="col-xs-12">
  <button type="button" name="button" class="deleFav" ng-click="getFavWeather(citySelected)">Get</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do not forget to accept the answer to report your problem is solved

Answer (score -2):

Do something like this:

```
<label class="item item-input">
        <textarea placeholder="Comments"  ng-model="textModel" ></textarea>
</label>
 <a class="button button-positive" ng-lick="closeModal(textModel)">Save</a>
```

Comment: Try adding comment to your code. *WHY* should the OP "do this"? Also keep in mind that this question is almost 1 year old so it is *very* unlikely the OP is still having this problem, especially since there is already an accepted solution.

Comment: what is `ng-lick` ?